# how to wrap each line inside a textarea by html tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to replace each `lorem ipsum` with `<p>lorem ipsum</p>` inside a textarea.

So each line should be wrapped by `<p>...</p>`.

I'm searching on google to find what code I could try - without success.

Any help?

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  // add <p> and </p>
});
```

```css
.txa{
display:block;
width:100%;
resize:none;
height:30vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea class='txa'>
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
</textarea>
<br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: so you want to add <p> tags as a text to show in the text area?

Comment: @RajanSharma, yes, that's it, as a text, not as really `p` tags

Comment: [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/replace) and regular expressions.

Comment: @qadenza updated my answer with a snippet sorry for the delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to capture every lines

```
// capture everything up to a newline
/(.*[^\n])/g
```

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $(".txa").val($(".txa").val().replace(/(.*[^\n])/g, "<p>$1</p>"));
});
```

```css
.txa{
display:block;
width:100%;
resize:none;
height:30vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea class='txa'>
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
bla bla
Hello world
lorem ipsum
</textarea>
<br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: Regex: Why only have  1 problem when you can have 2!

Comment: hehe nice quote from Jamie Zawinski

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of `map` and `join` to split the text apart, wrap it in your `<p></p>` tags and set the value back to the textarea.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  var text = $('.txa').val();
  var result = text.split("\n")
                   .filter(x => x.length > 0)
                   .map(t => `<p>${t}</p>`)
                   .join("\n");
  $('.txa').val(result)
});
```

```css
.txa{
display:block;
width:100%;
resize:none;
height:30vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea class='txa'>
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
</textarea>
<br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: there is an extra `<p></p>`

Comment: @qadenza theres an extra line break!

Comment: @qadenza Ive added a `filter` in to remove any empty entries

Answer (score 2):

Use `replace` with a simple regex.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $(".txa").html($(".txa").html().replace(/(lorem ipsum)/g, "&lt;p&gt;$1&lt;/p&gt;"));
});
```

```css
.txa {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
  height: 30vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<textarea class='txa'>
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
</textarea>
<br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

If the actual result is each line in `<p></p>`:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $(".txa").html($(".txa").html().split("\n").map(e => `<p>${e}</p>`).join("\n"));
});
```

```css
.txa {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
  height: 30vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<textarea class='txa'>
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum</textarea>
<br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: This assumes that the text will only ever be 'lorem ipsum' which seems very brittle. It would seem safe to assume this text is only an example from the OP and the actual solution needs to work with the line breaks in any provided text

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for the input, I'll add that.

Answer (score 1):

So tried a different take which fixes the bad behavior where either doesn't update your lines if they are typed after page load or the duplicating issue with the "p" tags.

This will only update the lines if that line has no existing "p" tags. if it does it will remove them first then replace the string, this is so that there are no duplicate tags

Hope you like it.

```js
function insertLine() {

  var lines = $('textarea').val().split('\n');
  var newLines = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {

    if (lines[i] !== "" && !lines[i].includes('<p>')) {
      newLines += '<p>' + lines[i] + '</p>';
      newLines += '\n';
    } else if (lines[i] !== "") {
      lines[i] = lines[i].replace('<p>', '');
      lines[i] = lines[i].replace('</p>', '');
      lines[i] = lines[i].replace(/(.*[^\n])/g, '<p>' + lines[i] + '</p>');
      newLines += lines[i];
      newLines += '\n';
    }
  }
  $('.txa').val(newLines);
}
```

```css
.txa {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
  height: 30vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="txa">
text 1
text 2
text 3
Type a few lines of your own.

</textarea>
</br>
<button onclick="insertLine();">RUN</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for writing this code! It's very helpful for me!